# json_encode produce JSON_ERROR_UTF8 from MSSQL-SELECT

Tags: php, sql-server, json, select, special-characters

I have an annoying problem with a database query to mssql. If the result contains special characters like the german 'ä', I cannot use *json_encode* to get the result as json correctly.

*json_last_error* return *5* which is equal to *JSON_ERROR_UTF8*. I guess the database does not return the values as *UTF-8* encoded. The database collection is *Latin1_General_CI_AS* and the affected columns are *varchars*.

The php *mssql.charset* configuration has no effect.

I read that mysql users could use `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');` to encode the return values correctly. What can I do, to get the values correctly for mssql?

*Hint -  I cannot change the anything at the database.*

Comment: try php's iconv() before json_encode()

Comment: `utf8_encode` the data first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before you JSON encode, use `utf8_encode()` around the string.

Comment: It seams to be the best solution. Just iterrate throught the results and convert. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set this in your connection also:

```
$result = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, array(
    'UID' => $username,
    'PWD' => $password,
    'Database' => $database,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"   // <---- here the magic happens 
));
```

For me, this is the easer way.