# Php json_encode($array) return nothing while $array contain HTML values

Tags: php, json

`json_encode($array)` return nothing while my `$array` contain HTML

below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 68
            [product_s_desc] => 
            [product_desc] => <p>Met dit pakket wordt de kerst één groot feest! Het is gevuld met verschillende lekkernijen, afkomstig uit Italië. Zowel jong en oud kan genieten van de heerlijke chocolade. Voor de echte Italiaanse liefhebbers zijn er de cantuccinis, de typisch Italiaanse amandelkoekjes.<br /><br />Inhoud: 4 artikelen:</p>

<ul>

<li>Dark Chocolate Pralines, "Le Perle", 80 gr</li>

<li>Cantuccini met chocolade, 100 gr</li>

<li>Melk Chocolade reep "Lindt", 100 gr</li>

<li>Snoepjes "Baratti Candies", 80 gr</li>

<li>Verpakt in giftbox</li>

</ul>
            [product_name] => Italiaans feest
            [metadesc] => 
            [metakey] => 
            [customtitle] => 
            [slug] => italiaans-feest
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to figure out, which error might have occurred?

Comment: I'm use try catch but nothing to display also my error reporting is on

Comment: `echo json_last_error()` and `var_dump(json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))`?

Comment: json_last_error() return 5 @kingkero

Comment: 5 => JSON_ERROR_UTF8 reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: Here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247737/json-encode-produce-json-error-utf8-from-mssql-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure out issue by using utf8_encode();