# PHP json_encode array(3) return false

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I have a `mysqli` query that returns a `multidimensional array`.

I'm trying to encode the php array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["cod_evento"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["titulo"]=>
    string(20) "Fiesta de cumpleaños"
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(23) "Mi fiesta de cumpleaños"
    ["puntuacion"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["direccion"]=>
    string(13) "c/ falsa 1234"
    ["imagen"]=>
    string(115) "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(19) "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
    ["cod_usuario"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }

  [....]
}
```

But when I try `json_encode($array)` it returns `bool(false)`

When I try to encode an array(2) or (1), then it works.

Comment: I don't see any issues. It should work fine. Can you post more code?

Comment: In the event of a failure to encode, [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) can be used to determine the exact nature of the error.... so have you tried checking what that error is?

Comment: Thanks, json_last_error() returns JSON_ERROR_UTF8. one string contained a ñ.

Comment: how I can include this character in the encode

Answer (score 2):

The error happened because your array had a non-unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.

to see the reason of failure

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

To answer the question in the comments

[json_encode produce JSON_ERROR_UTF8 from MSSQL-SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247737/json-encode-produce-json-error-utf8-from-mssql-select)